# Click on image go to another page but on 3th image slider for example (bootstrap slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, gallery

I need help..
I have a gallery of images on one page and slider on the other one. I need when I click on 3th image on gallery that slider start from that picture on the slider on the other page.

http://today.danijel.host56.com/pages/bath_coll.html  ==galery==
http://today.danijel.host56.com/pages/single/bath1.html  ==slider==

Is that possible?
This doesn`t work..

Comment: where is slider have you implemented or not  ?

Comment: Yes. Second link.. Slider is implemented but I don`t know what I have to do when I click on 3th image in gallery slider start from 3th image..